# CSS right div position not behaving as expected

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 #content {
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 }
.left { float: left; }
.middle { margin-left:511px; float: none;  }
.right {   float: right;   width: 115px;  }
#footer {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-bottom:11px;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>css test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">I have a dream</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="left">I am left</div>
        <div class="middle">I am middle</div>
        <div class="right">I am  right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> I am in the footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my html source code.
It displayed in the browser like below.
[image]

My question is why "I am right" is below of "I am middle". I think they should have the same height. How can I improve my css style. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the your corrected [**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7Ahf/). Following is your corrected CSS

```
.middle { margin-left:511px; float: left;  }

#footer {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-bottom:11px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to your `.middle` class instead of `float:none;`

`div` is a `block` element and i.e. its takes the full width, for making it to work as you mentioned add `float:left;` to the `middle class`.

Output -

[image: float]

Comment: Great! It works. But I still cannot understand Why 'float: left;' should be used? Why the 'I am  right' will sink if I didn't use   'float: left;'

Comment: @liamxu you should read about block and inline elements http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block` to your `class="left, middle, right"`.

**Problems With float**

The problem when you have float in your CSS code is that you need to take some precaution to make the surrounding element to encompass the floated elements, and also to avoid following elements in the code to sneak up next to it.

Another problem is that if you have a floated list that will take up several rows (visually speaking) and the content is of varying height, you are in for a world of hurt.

To learn more about inline-block refer [Robert's Page](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbM3R/) for reference.